# Fabric material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, world

could anyone help me to set up a fabric material of a traditional Bedouin tent. I am trying also to define available world setting as desert environment. My material doesn't look as what i would like. Please any suggestion will be very appreciated.

Tent fabric
[image]

My model[image]

Fabric material
[image]

Texture example
[image]

World 
[image]

THANKS!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Try to use pbr materials. https://www.textures.com/browse/pbr-materials/114558#fabrics-leather-and-paper

Comment: Thanks, I have checked but I don't need other textures, I would like understand how to make a realistic fabric material to apply the texture above with it. Thanks very much!

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time, make as many posts as necessary

Comment: Thanks Duarte, I would like to make a fabric material and use the texture above. The structure above is 42 m tall, could this be a problem?? thanks very much.

Comment: Looks like your texture is too small and repeated with high frequency. You need to texture coordinates for your texture or unwrap your mesh.